# Drop events from metricbeat is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

Could you please help me with an issue about metricbeat?
I have tried to set up a new drop_events (processors) but unsucessfully.
I want to drop every events that doesn't have "system".
Can you please let me know if it is possible to do that?

See what I set up in metricbeat.yml file

I really appreciate your help and time

```
drop_event.when:
  not:
    has_fields: ['system']
```

Follow the example below:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2021-07-13T08:03:27.547Z",
    "@metadata": {
        "beat": "metricbeat",
        "type": "_doc",
        "version": "7.10.0"
    },
    "event": {
        "dataset": "system.diskio",
        "module": "system"
    },
    "metricset": {
        "period": 60000,
        "name": "diskio"
    },
    "fields": {
        "uuid": "*********************************"
    },
    "ecs": {
        "version": "1.6.0"
    },
    "agent": {
        "hostname": "************",
        "ephemeral_id": "****************************",
        "id": "*************************************",
        "name": "***********",
        "type": "metricbeat",
        "version": "7.10.0"
    },
    "service": {
        "type": "system"
    },
    "host": {
        "disk": {
            "read.bytes": 237568,
            "write.bytes": 2743296
        },
        "name": "**********"
    },
    "tag": "metricbeat",
    "customer_id": "3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet provided does not follow the syntax of processors documented in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/defining-processors.html.

According to the documentation it should be

```
processors:
  - drop_event:
      when:
        not:
          has_fields: ['system']
```

Comment: Hello, We did tried try that already but didn't work eiher..

Comment: What does the Metricbeat log say?

Comment: Hi, there is no error messages into the log file

Comment: It is a winrdows server, do you know how can I get it?